# Displaying UIAlertView after some time

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uialertview, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to display a UIAlertView after some time (like 5 minutes after doing something in the app). I'm already notifying the user if the app is closed or in background. But I want to display a UIAlertView while the app is running.

I tried to dispatch_async as follows but the alert is popping forever:

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:minutes];
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
       ^{
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title!" message:@"message!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
       }
       );
```

Also, I read that the thread dies after 30 to 60 minutes. I want to be able to display the alert after more than 60 min.

Comment: I'm intrigued, where did you read thread dies after 30 to 60 minutes?

Comment: I can't really find where i read it, but i believe i did. I will test it tomorrow and get back to you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not use an [`NSTimer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html), why would you need to use GCD in this case?

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5*60 target:self selector:@selector(showAlert:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Then, within the same class, you'd have something like this:

```
- (void) showAlert:(NSTimer *) timer {
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title!" 
                                                     message:@"message!" 
                                                    delegate:self               
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Also, as [@PeyloW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165059/peylow) noted, you can use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` too:

```
UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title!" 
                                                 message:@"message!" 
                                                delegate:self               
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert performSelector:@selector(show) withObject:nil afterDelay:5*60];
[alert release];
```

**EDIT** You can now also use GCD's `dispatch_after` API:

```
double delayInSeconds = 5;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title!"
                                                        message:@"message"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release]; //Obviously you should not call this if you're using ARC
});
```

Comment: Or simply use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, and you won't need to mess with a timer either. Fact is you can call the `show` method on the `UIAlertView` and no need for a second method either.

Comment: @PeyloW Good point, although you may run into race conditions with that as (i think) `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` actually performs the selector on a secondary thread. Also, when would you `release` it? The autorelease pool may deallocate the `UIAlertView` object before it has a chance to perform the `show` selector. I think it's worth it to use a `NSTimer` in this case.

Comment: `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` will always perform the selector on the current thread, and the object is retained by the current run-loop until it is performed (or cancelled). In practice a timer is implicitly created. The API would be pretty useless and not conforming to Cocoa memory management rules otherwise. So both if your fears are baseless.

Comment: @PeyloW That actually makes a lot of sense - I learned something new today, thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I totally missed that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of thing that Local Notifications were created for. You can set an UIAlertView-like notification to come up some time in the future, even if your app is backgrounded or not running at all.

[Here](http://icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/) is a tutorial.