# Timed UIAlert Fires every 60s No Matter What delay I Use

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

Im wanting to show an alert when the user has been using the app for an hour

In the app delegate:

First I tried this: [Displaying UIAlertView after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597628/displaying-uialertview-after-some-time)

Then I tried

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[self performSelector:@selector(showAlert) withObject:nil afterDelay:3600];

return YES;
}

-(void)showAlert{
  UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title!"
                                                 message:@"message!"
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
}
```

In both examples I tried using various figures in the `after delay`.  No matter what I put for the delay, the timer fires after a min every time?

UPDATE:
This is correct code, I had also left this in the viewDidLoad in my view controller in addition to delegate so it was also firing that method.  Thanks all

Comment: Is your sample code all part of the same method?  If the `@selector()` is a calling another method, containing the next two lines of code, it should work.  Please add additional code for clarification.

Comment: Have you maybe considered using a notification to handle this timer? Set the fire date 60 min in the future and just handle your action/alert in the notification section? If the app isn't active, you can just ignore the notif or remove it when the app is closed.

Comment: edited to show more code, this is literally all the code as its a test app, nothing else has been changed all I've done is add the above method to the delegates didfifnshlaunching

Comment: Thanks all updated question to explain why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is what you do:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [self performSelector:@selector(showAlert) withObject:nil afterDelay:3600];

    return YES;
}

-(void)showAlert{
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title!"
                                                     message:@"message!"
                                                    delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

you should edit your question to this, and add additional information, as the problem has to be somewhere else.

Otherwise, this is your answer.

Comment: Thanks fo reply, it confirmed that I was coding it properly, then when hunting and found id left this method in the viewDidLoad.  Marking as correct as your coding is correct and led me to find the answer

Answer (score 1):

your code should work are you sure you are not calling `showAlert` elsewhere ? 
You can also try this, just to make sure :

```
  long long int anHourInNanoSec = 60*60*NSEC_PER_SEC;
  long long int anHourFromNow = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, anHourInNanoSec);

  dispatch_after(anHourFromNow, dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
            [self showAlert];
        });
```

By the way, I'm not sure your method will be launched if app is used for an hour. If  app is set to background you should stop the timer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, yes thats exactly what was happening sorted just before your answer came though! Thats good point, Any tips/code on that method when it goes into background?  Plus one for you for that helpful tid bit!

Comment: My first thought is to store the remaining time at launch. Then to create a "daemon" that will trigger the alert when timer run off. 

The daemon may decrease the remaining every 1 or 5 sec then goes to sleep ; and trigger the alert when remaining time is lesser or equal to 0.

Doing so, you just have to stop your daemon when application enters background mode, and to reactivate it when your app is back to foreground.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry fo new answer but comment field is too short, you can try something like :

... .h

> @property  (nonatomic, assign) long long int remainingTime;
>   @property  (nonatomic, assign) BOOL deamonPaused;

... .m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {

   long long int anHourInNanoSec = 60*60*NSEC_PER_SEC;
   _remainingTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, anHourInNanoSec);
   _deamonPaused = NO;

   dispatch_queue_t deamonThread = dispatch_queue_create(@"deamonThread", NULL);
   dispatch_async(deamonThread, ^{
            [self launchDeamon];
        });
    dispatch_release(deamonThread);

    return YES; 
}

- (void) launchDeamon{
   while (_remainingTime > 0){
      if (!_deamonPaused)
         _remainingTime -= 5*NSEC_PER_SEC; 
      sleep(5);
   }
   [self showAlert];
}

- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
    _deamonPaused = YES; 
}

- (void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{
   _deamonPaused = NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Citron, im going to give that a go! Have another plus 1 on me!