# UIAlertView with timer

Tags: ios, timer, uialertview, nstimer

I'm trying to make a `UIAlertView` with a `timer`. For example: The user sets a time, the user taps a button, a `UIAlertView` pops up and in the alertView there is a timer showing how long the user has to wait before an action will start.

When searching the web I only found how to show how much time has passed. Is there a way to **update the UIAlertView every second** to show the timer? After the time has passed, the UIAlertView needs to be dismissed and a void has to be called.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597628/displaying-uialertview-after-some-time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try like it.

```
UIAlertView *autosaveAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Close" message:@"Autosave in (%d) seconds" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Press to cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[autosaveAlert show];

for(int i = 10; i>=0; i--){
    NSString *tmp = @"Close in (%d) seconds";
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:tmp, i];
    [autosaveAlert setMessage:str];
    CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode,1, false);
}

[autosaveAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:TRUE];
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the following warning: Implicit declaration of function "AMLocalizedString" is invalid in C99.

Comment: @ArthurMe Sorry I have remove AMLocalizedString. It is used for localiazation. Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can keep a pointer to the alert view & modify its message, title & dismiss it with any button index you choose. Refer to the [UIAlertView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) document for proper method names.

Comment: Thank you, I also tried it this way and it works just fine :)